# Export .page to .html

Tags: html, css, pygtk, mallard

I will write help for my PyGTK app. The help consists of [`.page` files](https://github.com/umpirsky/revision-monitor/tree/master/help/C). I would like to export this help to HTML/CSS and publish it as online help on app website.

Is there a tool which can export it to HTML/CSS or some other standard format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By ".page files" you mean Mallard? Use `yelp-build`, like so:

```
yelp-build html -o outputdir *.page
```